# Android: AutoCompleteTextView show suggestions when no text entered

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView`, when the user clicks on it, I want to show suggestions even if it has no text - but `setThreshold(0)` works exactly the same as `setThreshold(1)` - so the user has to enter at least 1 character to show the suggestions.

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 177, accepted):

This is [documented behavior](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29):

> When `threshold` is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is
>   applied.

You can manually show the drop-down via `showDropDown()`, so perhaps you can arrange to show it when you want. Or, subclass `AutoCompleteTextView` and override `enoughToFilter()`, returning `true` all of time.

Comment: The showDropDown() seem to work well on seting onClickListener,but subclass thing is not working untill the user enter a letter and comes dels back.But not just with onClick...

Comment: This works just perfectly in combination with OnFocusChangeListener that calls showDropDown() when the view gains the focus.

Comment: I have to also override the onFocusChanged, as stated on the answer below by @David Vávra

Comment: @commonsWare `showDropDown()` isn't working in `afterTextChanged` when `.getText().toString().length()==0`. WHYYY

Comment: Only overriding enoughToFilter helps me. Thank you!

Comment: works like a charm. use setOnFocusChangeListener then call showDropDown() on the AutocompleteTextView.

Answer (score 138):

Here is my class *InstantAutoComplete*. It's something between `AutoCompleteTextView` and `Spinner`.

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
            Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (focused && getAdapter() != null) {
            performFiltering(getText(), 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Use it in your xml like this:

```
<your.namespace.InstantAutoComplete ... />
```

Comment: That's great! I'd also like to point out that in your layout XML file you have to change `<AutoCompleteTextView ... />` to `<your.namespace.InstantAutoComplete ... />`. I lost some time figuring this out :)

Comment: Great class - only suggestion would be in the onFocusChanged method, change the "if (focused)" to "if (focused && getAdapter() != null)".

Comment: For **AndroidX**, extend `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`.

Answer (score 55):

Easiest way:

Just use setOnTouchListener and showDropDown()

```
AutoCompleteTextView text;
.....
.....
text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
      text.showDropDown();
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: To make this even better use  if(!text.isPopupShowing()){
                    text.showDropDown();
                }

Comment: not much common, but this won't work in case the user doesn't touch in order to go to this EditText. For example when using a remote control with buttons (Android TV, for example).

Comment: You should use setOnFocusChanged. Somebody can have keyboard and press TAB button or using mouse and touch listener will not be called.

Comment: onTouchListener will get called different times for a single tap - Ex: the event can be MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. So its better to check for a specific event and write the code

Comment: Wasted 2 whole day and you solved my problem man, thnx alot. @user1913469

Answer (score 18):

Destil's code works just great when there is only one `InstantAutoComplete` object. **It didn't work with two though** - no idea why. But when I put `showDropDown()` (just like CommonsWare advised) into `onFocusChanged()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused) {
        performFiltering(getText(), 0);
        showDropDown();
    }
}
```

it solved the problem.

It is just the two answers properly combined, but I hope it may save somebody some time.

Comment: Your addition helped, but I got an error if there was text in the InstantAutoComplete and the screen orientation changed. I fixed it with a check on the window visibility, I posted the new code here: https://gist.github.com/furycomptuers/4961368

Answer (score 11):

The adapter does not perform filtering initially.
When the filtering is not performed, the dropdown list is empty.
so you might have to get the filtering going initially.

To do so, you can invoke `filter()` after you finish adding the entries:

```
adapter.add("a1");
adapter.add("a2");
adapter.add("a3");
adapter.getFilter().filter(null);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use onFocusChangeListener;

```
TCKimlikNo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                TCKimlikNo.showDropDown();

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Destil's answer above almost works, but has one subtle bug.  When the user first gives focus to the field it works, however if they leave and then return to the field it will not show the drop down because the value of mPopupCanBeUpdated will still be false from when it was hidden.  The fix is to change the onFocusChanged method to:

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused) {
        if (getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            // We want to trigger the drop down, replace the text.
            setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but this also means that the text will be reset (though that's quite ok usually)...

Answer (score 6):

Just call this method on touch or click event of autoCompleteTextView or where you want.

```
autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()
```

Comment: I had to extend AppAutoCompleteTextView, and add showDropDown() in `onFocusedChanges()` as per the post made by Nasif Md. Tanjim.

Answer (score 3):

To make CustomAutoCompleteTextView.
1. override setThreshold,enoughToFilter,onFocusChanged method

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView  extends AutoCompleteTextView { 

    private int myThreshold; 

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView  (Context context) { 
        super(context); 
    } 

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView  (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { 
        super(context, attrs, defStyle); 
    } 

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView  (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
        super(context, attrs); 
    } 
     //set threshold 0.
    public void setThreshold(int threshold) { 
        if (threshold < 0) { 
            threshold = 0; 
        } 
        myThreshold = threshold; 
    } 
    //if threshold   is 0 than return true
    public boolean enoughToFilter() { 
         return true;
        } 
    //invoke on focus 
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
            Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
                    //skip space and backspace 
        super.performFiltering("", 67);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

    }

    protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.performFiltering(text, keyCode);
    }

    public int getThreshold() { 
        return myThreshold; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
    searchAutoComplete.setThreshold(0);
    searchAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {//cut last probel
                    if (charSequence.length() > 1) {
                        if (charSequence.charAt(charSequence.length() - 1) == ' ') {
                            searchAutoComplete.setText(charSequence.subSequence(0, charSequence.length() - 1));
                            searchAutoComplete.setSelection(charSequence.length() - 1);
                        }
                    }
                   }


                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                }
            });


    //when clicked in autocomplete text view
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
              case R.id.header_search_etv:
                    if (searchAutoComplete.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        searchAutoComplete.setText(" ");
                    }
             break;
            }
        }):
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, pseudo code:

```
    public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (focused) {
            performFiltering(getText(), 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.showDropDown();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I couldn't add `onTouchEvent()` but I added `showDropDown()` after `performFiltering(getText(), 0)` in `onFocusChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

Seven years later, guys, the problem stays the same. Here's a class with a function which forces that stupid pop-up to show itself in any conditions. All you need to do is to set an adapter to your AutoCompleteTextView, add some data into it, and call `showDropdownNow()` function anytime.

Credits to @David Vávra. It's based on his code.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView

class InstantAutoCompleteTextView : AutoCompleteTextView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun enoughToFilter(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    fun showDropdownNow() {
        if (adapter != null) {
            // Remember a current text
            val savedText = text

            // Set empty text and perform filtering. As the result we restore all items inside of
            // a filter's internal item collection.
            setText(null, true)

            // Set back the saved text and DO NOT perform filtering. As the result of these steps
            // we have a text shown in UI, and what is more important we have items not filtered
            setText(savedText, false)

            // Move cursor to the end of a text
            setSelection(text.length)

            // Now we can show a dropdown with full list of options not filtered by displayed text
            performFiltering(null, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

on FocusChangeListener, check

```
if (hasFocus) {
            tvAutoComplete.setText(" ")
```

in your filter, just trim this value:

```
filter { it.contains(constraint.trim(), true) }
```

and it will show all suggestion when you focus on this view.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this to your onCreate Method in Java

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Loc_names));

    textView1 =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acT1);
    textView1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {
            textView1.setMaxLines(5);
            textView1.showDropDown();

        }
    });
```

And this to your Xml file...

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:hint="@string/select_location"
            android:id="@+id/acT1"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

And create an Array in string.xml under Values...

```
<string-array name="Loc_names">

        <item>Pakistan</item>
        <item>Germany</item>
        <item>Russia/NCR</item>
        <item>China</item>
        <item>India</item>
        <item>Sweden</item>
        <item>Australia</item>
    </string-array>
```

And you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

For me, It is :

```
 autoCompleteText.setThreshold(0);
```

do the trick.