# How to show menu options at the end of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to EditText with arrow at the end and when you tap on edittext it will pop up with the options. Since i am unable to upload image, i have to describe it.

Same type of edit text is available in default Contacts Application comes in ICS. When you add new contact, it will have edit text with options.

Thanks
Chintan

Comment: What type of options? There is such a thing as an `AutoCompleteTextView`, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: in autoCompleteTextView, user has to type. in EditText with options, user can select it so no need to type

Comment: Please refer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126717/android-autocompletetextview-show-suggestions-when-no-text-entered

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this behavior if you just combine a `TextView` along side with an `ImageView` of your arrow that `onClick` will pop up a window with your options.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Is it when you have options for "Home, Mobile, Work", etc? That is the design of a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) in the post-Honeycomb world. On GB & below, it would give you a pop up dialog with the options instead.