# How to extend EditText/AutoCompleteTextView to show the last 'n' inputs?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-edittext

I want to show a list of the last 'n' entries when the user taps on a text input. 
How can I do it?

Right now I am extending EditText, incorporating the 'x' button to clear its content. So, my idea is incorporate this functionality to this widget

Comment: just add recent data entered to the adapter of ACTV

Comment: @pskink, It works, but some extra work has to be done to show the last entries and get the drop down list without user input. At the moment, I have not found how to show just the last 'n' entries.

Comment: use ArrayAdapter for example - it can use an array that you can change as you want

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @pskink put me on the correct way

First, the **AutoCompleteTextView** has to be reimplemented

```
public class QuickSayAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

private Context ctx;

public QuickSayAutoComplete(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ctx = context;
    init();
}

public QuickSayAutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ctx = context;
    init();
}

public QuickSayAutoComplete(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    ctx = context;
    init();
}
```

To add the last elements introduced, a **ClickListener** has to be added.

```
this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = getText().toString();

            // The text is not empty
            if ( (!text.matches("")) && (text.length() > 0)) {

                // The last element introduced will be the first
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getAdapter();
                adapter.remove(text);
                adapter.insert(text, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

The ACTV's adapter has to be an ArrayList, if not, [we cannot remove elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200631/670873)

```
    String[] array = {"Hello", "Good Morning", "Nice to see you"};
    ArrayList<String> greetings = new ArrayList<String>();
    greetings.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, greetings);
    setAdapter(adapter);
    setThreshold(0);
```

Finally, the DropDown list is shown (with all the entries) when the user touch the ACTV [and there is not text input yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504422/670873). As the user introduces an input, the list gets shorter. It could be perfect if we can limit the number of entries shown in this point

```
// TouchListener to show the list without user input
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        showDropDown();
        return false;
    }
});
```