# How to show dropdown of suggestions in autcompletetextview

Tags: android, autocomplete

I want to show all the suggestions to the user when the textfield is empty, I am getting my suggestions from json response, when user types the word it appears in dropdown but when the textfield is empty it doesn't show anything i even tried  `showDropDown()` but the Android Monitor says: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AutoCompleteTextView acTextView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
    acTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(this,acTextView.getText().toString()));
    acTextView.setThreshold(0);

    acTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            acTextView.showDropDown();
        }
    });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

i get my suggestion adapter from these classes first
**JSON Parser** which parse the keywords from URL.
**A getter setter** class. 
**Suggestions Adapter** which sets the filtered items in adapter.
My JSON response:

```
 [{"lookupValueId":350,"lookupTypeId":33,"lookupValue":"Java"},{"lookupValueId":351,"lookupTypeId":33,"lookupValue":"C++"},{"lookupValueId":352,"lookupTypeId":33,"lookupValue":"Photoshop"},{"lookupValueId":353,"lookupTypeId":33,"lookupValue":"Java Script"}]
```

JSON Parser Class:

```
public class JsonParse {


public List<SuggestGetSet> getParseJsonWCF(String sName)
{
    List<SuggestGetSet> ListData = new ArrayList<SuggestGetSet>();
    try {
        String temp = sName.replace(" ", "%20");
        URL js = new URL("http://SomeUrl" + temp + "%22%7D%7D");
                    URLConnection jc = js.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(line);
        System.out.print("DATA: " + line);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++){
            JSONObject r = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
            ListData.add(new SuggestGetSet(r.getInt("lookupValueId"),r.getString("lookupValue")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ListData;

   }
}
```

Getter setter class:

```
public class SuggestGetSet {
String name;
static Integer id;
public SuggestGetSet(int id, String name){
    this.setId(id);
    this.setName(name);
}
public static Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**And finally the Adapter class:**

```
class SuggestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private List<String> suggestions;

SuggestionAdapter(Activity context,String nameFilter) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suggestions.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return suggestions.get(index);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            JsonParse jp = new JsonParse();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and
                // returns an ArrayList<GoEuroGetSet>
                List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions = jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                suggestions.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < new_suggestions.size(); i++) {
                    suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getName());
                }

                // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults
                // object
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
  }
}
```

I followed this referrence: http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-autocompletetextview-example-json/

Comment: Follow this thread : [Show suggestions when no text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126717/android-autocompletetextview-show-suggestions-when-no-text-entered)

Comment: i went through that and many other tutorials and stackoverflow answers. Didnt found anything helpfull so finally posted a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the response first and pass arraylist from activity to your adapter.
your code

```
acTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(this,yourarraylist));
```

Comment: Currently i am doing like this:     `acTextView.setAdapter(new SuggestionAdapter(this,acTextView.getText().toString()));` this will pass my text and get suggestions. what exactly you want me to do? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nope not working. What i want to do is when user clicks the autocompletetextview it should show dropdown with all suggestions. \n This is how i am doing     



acTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            (@) Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                acTextView.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        acTextView.showDropDown();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

Comment: just use below code

autoTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    autoTextView.showDropDown();
   }
  });

Comment: As i have already mentioned in the question that i tried showDropDown but it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: When i click on autocompletetextview it says this: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: is your data is local ? or are you getting from any API? i am getting my suggestions from json response.

Comment: I already posted my code with my question. Please go through it once.

Comment: i am also getting from api

Comment: Dont call api in adapter

Comment: even Dont send text to adapter, you can do it from activity class

Comment: just do this:

Get the data from server and add into arrayList<String> and then 


ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AllState.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, stringlist);
       autoTextView.setThreshold(0);
       autoTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: Looks like this will work, but i am beginner so can you  please show me the full code? you can send me that in chat.

Comment: yes i am trying but if you provide the code i think it will help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: 1. ArrayList<String> stringlist = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Thanks @Geeta it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you need custom adapter if android provide you the component the same

Follow this [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example)  and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_autocompletetextview_control.htm)

suggestion as geeta said firstly create ArrayList from JSON than pass that to adpter which is best approach

hope this help you good luck

Comment: I successfully created array from my json response. How do i pass that array into my main activity?