# Show AutoCompleteTextView on the first click

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using the `AutoCompleteTextView` to show a dropdown list when the user enter a word , but I would like the dropdown list to show when he first tap in the field.
Maybe it would be better with a spinner but I would have no text input...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126717/android-autocompletetextview-show-suggestions-when-no-text-entered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: AutoCompleteTextView show suggestions when no text entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126717/android-autocompletetextview-show-suggestions-when-no-text-entered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown() in onTouch method.

```
mAnswer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mAnswer.showDropDown();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```